# What does the term "ticky-tacky" in the song "Little Boxes" mean and what is its etymology?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, technical

The song "Little Boxes" by Malvina Reynolds has these lyrics:

```
Little boxes on the hillside
Little boxes made of ticky-tacky
Little boxes on the hillside
Little boxes all the same
There's a pink one and a green one
And a blue one and a yellow one
And they're all made out of ticky-tacky
And they all look just the same
```

What does the term "ticky-tacky" mean and what is it's etymology? Is "ticky-tacky" some sort of building material?

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: You can look up ticky-tacky in a dictionary and on etymoline.com.  As I recall the song was about Daly City, just south of San Francisco, and its similar, cheaply built houses painted in various pastels.

Comment: The song was written by Berkeley alumna and political activist Malvina Reynolds in **1962**, before which ***ticky-tacky*** had [very little currency.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ticky-tacky%2Cticky-tack&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cticky%20-%20tacky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cticky%20-%20tack%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cticky%20-%20tacky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cticky%20-%20tack%3B%2Cc0) But I'm surprised to realise I've been "mishearing" it for all these decades. I could have sworn it was three-syllable ***ticky-tack*** (as apparently might some others).

Answer (score 2):

OED has this song as its first recorded use of *ticky-tacky.*

> *Originally U.S.*
> Inferior or cheap material, esp. that used in uniform suburban building.
>
> > 1962   M. Reynolds *Little Boxes* (1964) (song) 3   And they're all made out of ticky tacky, And they all look just the same.

They suggest that it's derived from a reduplication of *tacky,*

> Dowdy, shabby; in poor taste, cheap, vulgar. Also in combinations, as **tacky-looking** adj. *colloquial* (originally and chiefly *U.S.*).